# How to display a viewController from an extended iOS module

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am creating an Module in Titanium which is extended in iOS. In that module I am creating a viewController and I want to show it on the screen when i called that module.
Not able to figure it out.. What will be right approach for it.

Answer (score 1):

In the main TiModule, you have to use `[TiApp app]` for UIViewController. But just using this will give you error of Threading problem, so, we need to create another method to use `[TiApp app]`. E.G.

In startup method of the module write:

> ENSURE_UI_THREAD(OnMainUI, nil);

This ensures that the method which is passed as an argument runs on Main Thread because it has some UI related operation. Without this statement, you will receive error of UI rendering in background thread.

Then implement following method,

```
- (id) OnMainUI {
   UIViewController *controller = [INITIALIZATION OF CONTROLLER];
   [[TiApp app] showModalController: controller animated: YES];
}
```

So, this will open up the controller, which you created.

Comment: so we dont have to create any view and viewProxy??

Comment: I'm getting - Use of undeclared identifier 'TiApp' error. :-(

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya sorry for the delay. We don't need to have ViewProxy for the controller which is being opened in Modal Controller

Comment: @Udhaya you need to include "TiApp.h", like, #import "TiApp.h"

Comment: You might use Navigation Controller but I did not try it yet.